# Install Bluetooth inside a home theater, How?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I have a 5.1 home theater(old one), I would like to transform it into a audio streaming system. I have a Arduino UNO and HC-05 Bluetooth Module, and I don't know how to install it in my home theater(if it does). solution please...

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What are you wanting the Arduino to do?

Comment: I don't know, just mentioned that I have..

Comment: You want to use the arduino to override the buttons of your home theather?
Or do you want your arduino to send IR commands (same as a remote) to your home theather?

Comment: I just want to make my home theater into an A2DP bluetooth audio reciever..thats all..please give me solution regarding that..

Comment: @Harish Were you able to do it? Could you please share the details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this will be feasible. There are two main issues:

**1.** I don't think there's a sensible way to get the HC-05 module to work with A2DP. It's great for a simple serial connection, but Bluetooth-enabled media devices generally won't connect to it if they're looking for audio streaming systems (as far as I know).

**2.** The Uno probably isn't powerful enough. Even if you could get the audio data into it, I don't think it will be able to decode the information to an analog audio signal in real-time.

Something like a Raspberry Pi with a suitable Bluetooth module might be a better choice for this.

Comment: So could you suggest me any Bluetooth module that works like A2DP, so that I can install in my home theater.

Comment: I would suggest something like this, if you want your stereo to be able to receive music over bluetooth: 

http://www.tinydeal.com/en/Bluetooth-Music-Receiver-A2DP-Wireless-HiFi-3-5mm-Stereo-Audio-Dongle-Adapter-p-70931.html?currency=EUR&ship_to=NL&gclid=Cj0KEQjwgI6pBRDak6aRovWNqLsBEiQA8zZSLttsqa4WBkkKJSjTnlIndXji0IkOhH4QXCRPJiaEqyEaAly68P8HAQ

Cheaper as an arduino, way easier and actually possible.