# Can a connection of HC-05 and Arduino Nano receive audio and display waveform on computer?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

Working to receive Music for Bluetooth Speaker via HC-05

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't.  The HC-05 is a Bluetooth Serial device, Bluetooth speakers are Bluetooth Audio Sink devices.

It's like asking "Can my bicycle fly?"

[image]

I think you'll agree the answer is "NO".

The only possible way of doing it using the HC-05 is to receive the audio using your computer then pre-process it and send the important information to the Arduino through the HC-05, so the Arduino can then send it back to the computer for displaying.  But then, what *really* is the point of the Arduino...?!

Comment: So what bluetooth modules should I use to make a Bluetooth speaker?

Comment: Like I said - a bluetooth audio sink module. I don't know if there is a "module" as such available - you are probably best off getting a real set of bluetooth speakers or a bluetooth headset and ripping it apart.

Comment: Bluetooth audio modules are sold, often at a price premium.  It's possible that in some cases they may just be a different firmware on the same silicon, but as that is typically not released its not really a do-it-yourself modification.

Comment: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/9890/install-bluetooth-inside-a-home-theater-how   I too asked...